# Form POST using Ajax doesn't populate database in Django, but gives success message

Tags: django, ajax

VIEW:

```
class AddFoo(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'qualitylabs/add_foo.html'
    form_class = AddFooForm
    success_message = 'Success: Foo was created'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Home')
```

FORM:

```
class AddFooForm(BSModalModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'part_number': PartNumberWidget,
            'operation': OperationNumberWidget,
        }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function sendToServer(machine, before, after) {
    var modified_form_data = before + "&inspection_machine=" + encodeURIComponent(machine) + after
    $.ajax({
        type: $('#AddFooForm').attr('method'),
        url: $('#AddFooForm').attr('action'),
        data: modified_form_data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('did it!!!!!')
        }
    });
}
```

I'm trying to post a form to the server, which should populate the database. I have to send it in Ajax because I have to iterate multiple times, changing variables each time (poorly set up database). The weirdest thing is that when I run the code, I get:

"POST /add_foo/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

which is the same result that you get when the server responds properly. The page does not redirect to the success_url, and when I check the data in the admin page, the items have not been added. However, in the admin page I do get the success message of "Sucess: Foo was created"

Any ideas? It's quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

I was copying off of some previous code that had used BSModalModelForm because they were using modal forms, but I wasn't. Once I changed it to CreateView it worked.